# GMAP3 - Google map API3 trigger marker click event from external url

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

Using GMAP3 Google Map API 3 class.  Cannot quite figure out how to trigger the click event on a marker from an external link via javascript.  I have tried the v3 api syntax but suspect that I am missing something in relation to the GMAP3 library.  Could anyone help me out here?

I am showing a map with markers and infobox data from an ajax request with a resulting JSON array.  Works great.  I assign a click event to the marker and it works fine.  I am using parsing that same JSON array to populate a datatable with a `<a href="#" id="link" arid="X">Click Me</a>`

X is actually the incrementing marker counter I used when building the JSON array, so it would start with 0 and build to whatever value represents all my markers.  I am expecting to use this value to tell GMAP3 which marker I want to pass the click event to...  if this though process is wrong then I am really confused.

My JSON array object is stored in markerlist and passed to the function below... which works great but I cannot seem to trigger those clicks from my datatable links... (see my jquery code below to grab those clicks and attempt to pass them along to the map)

My map code is:

```
    function display( markerlist ) {

$("#map").gmap3({action:'clear'});

$("#map").gmap3(
{action: 'init',
options:{
center:true,
zoom:13,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {
style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
},
navigationControl: true,
scrollwheel: true,
streetViewControl: true
}
},
{action: 'addMarkers',
radius:100,
markers: markerlist,
clusters:{
maxZoom: 10,
// This style will be used for clusters with more than 0 markers
20: {
content: '<div class="cluster cluster-1">CLUSTER_COUNT</div>',
width: 53,
height: 52
},
// This style will be used for clusters with more than 20 markers
50: {
content: '<div class="cluster cluster-2">CLUSTER_COUNT</div>',
width: 56,
height: 55
},
// This style will be used for clusters with more than 50 markers
100: {
content: '<div class="cluster cluster-3">CLUSTER_COUNT</div>',
width: 66,
height: 65
}

},
marker: {
options: {

clickable: true
},
events:{
click: function(marker,event,data) {
$(this).gmap3({action: 'clear', name : 'infowindow'});
$(this).gmap3({action: 'addinfowindow', anchor: marker, options: { content:
'<div class="text"><strong><div style="color:navy;">' + data.itype + '</strong><br/><div id="address" snum="' + data.streetnum + '" snam="' + data.streetnam + '" styp="' + data.streettyp + '">'+ data.iaddress +'</div><br/>' + data.inum + '<br/>'+ data.datetime +'</div><hr>'+data.notes+'</div>'} })
}, 
mouseover: function(marker, event, data){
$(this).gmap3(
{ action:'clear', name:'overlay'},
{ action:'addOverlay',
latLng: marker.getPosition(),
content:    '<div class="infobulle">' +
'<div class="bg"></div>' +
'<div class="text">' + data.itype +'</div>' +
'</div>' +
'<div class="arrow"></div>',
offset: {
x:-46,
y:-73
}
});
},
mouseout: function(){
$(this).gmap3({action:'clear', name:'overlay'});
}

}, //end events
callback: function(result){
if (result){
//not doing anything with a callback at this time
} else {
alert('Bad callback...');
}
} //end callbacks
} // end marker

}
,{action:"autofit"} //end action

);


$("a#link").live('click',function(markerlist){ // this works and I can get my arid ok, but the trigger won't work
var arid = $(this).attr('arid');
google.maps.event.trigger(markerlist[arid], 'click');
return false;
});



};
```

Any help would really be appreciated and am sure will be useful to others!

Comment: I exactly have same issue!! This GMAP3 documentation is little bit hard. So reading the code directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is markerlist is not a global variable, it's local to your `display` function?  What do you get if you write markerlist to the console in your `click` event handler?